# Error Running Django tutorial : Page not found

Tags: python, django

I am facing trouble while running the tutorial for Django. I have attached the error details and the complete code. I am using python 3.x, django 2.0.x with anaconda distribution on python.

*Error details*

[image]

Comment: website\urls.py 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('music', include('music.urls', namespace=None)),
]

Comment: the error says it itself, `Page not found`, means one of URL  patterns is not correct

Comment: the issue is i have everything as per the tutorial to configure my first app url

Comment: where is your `music.urls`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a slash in the path that includes the music urls.

It should be:

```
path('music/', include('music.urls')),
```